# Connect my app to online MySQL server (workbench)

Tags: java, android, mysql

So I have created an `app` and now I am trying to connect it to a `MySQL Server`. I am currently working from `eclipse` through `AVD`.

So my code for connecting to the `SQL Server`:

```
try{

    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://xxxx:3306/cl49-takeawa-cc7","cl49-takeawa-cc7","xxxx");
    PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement("select * from app_users where user_username='"+username2+"'");


    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();
    while(rs.next()){

        String username = rs.getString("user_username");

        if(username.equals(username2)){

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "This user already exist! Please try another name", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        }

    }
    user_id++;

    PreparedStatement st1 = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO user (user_id,user_realname,user_username,user_password,user_house_number,user_postcode,user_address,user_email) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
    st1.setLong(1, user_id);
    st1.setString(2, fullname1);
    st1.setString(3, username2);
    st1.setString(4, password1);
    st1.setString(5, housenumber1);
    st1.setString(6, postcode2);
    st1.setString(7, address1);
    st1.setString(8, email1);
    st1.executeUpdate();
    st1.close();

    con.close();


}catch(Exception ex){

    System.out.println(ex);

}
```

And this is the `error` that I get:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
```

Any help?

**Edit:**

```
        else{        
            new PostTask();
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You have created an account! Time to eat!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();   
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(myIntent);
            }
        }
    });



}
// The definition of our task class
   private class PostTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
   @Override
   protected void onPreExecute() {
      super.onPreExecute();
   }

   @Override
   protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
      String url=params[0];
      try{

            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://xxxx:3306/cl49-takeawa-cc7","cl49-takeawa-cc7","xxxx");
            PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement("select * from app_users where user_username='"+username2+"'");

            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();
            while(rs.next()){

                 String username = rs.getString("user_username");

                 if(username.equals(username2)){

                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "This user already exist! Please try another name", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                 }

             }
            user_id++;

            PreparedStatement st1 = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO user (user_id,user_realname,user_username,user_password,user_house_number,user_postcode,user_address,user_email) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
            st1.setLong(1, user_id);
            st1.setString(2, fullname1);
            st1.setString(3, username2);
            st1.setString(4, password1);
            st1.setString(5, housenumber1);
            st1.setString(6, postcode2);
            st1.setString(7, address1);
            st1.setString(8, email1);
            st1.executeUpdate();
            st1.close();

            con.close();


        }catch(Exception ex){

            System.out.println(ex);

        }
    return url;
   }

   @Override
   protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
      super.onProgressUpdate(values);
   }

   @Override
   protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
      super.onPostExecute(result);
   }
   }        

}
```

Now I don't get something back in the `LogCat`, but also I don't get any update on `MySQL Server`

Answer (score 0):

Add mysql jdbc connector and add to your project,It will solve the problem.

Comment: I have already added it in my libs folder and in Java Build Path

Comment: try with mysql 3.0.17 connector and place all your access to `mysql` db inside an Asyn_Task

Comment: Are you sure? is there another way to do it?
And also do you mean `AsyncTask`?

Comment: Yeah.Android dosen't directly communicate with `mySQL` you must want to have `AsynTask` to connect with remote `mySQL` also connector 3.0.17 only supports .

Comment: Can you give me an example how to do an `AsyncTask` for `mySQL`?

Comment: Check this http://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2012/03/17/understanding-asynctask-once-and-forever/

Comment: I update it! But I don't get any response back from the `MySQL Server`!

Comment: where u tested the app? in the emulator or in your phone ?

Comment: In the emulator, I don't have a phone (with the latest Android version) to test it. I will try another way to do that, but thanks anyway!

Comment: I don't know if it's correct, until it will be executable!

Answer (score -1):

Go to
https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/
and download the jdbc driver and add to your class path